# How do I print the deleted lines in a file to a new file in a single command?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

For Example:
File A contains 20 lines and I delete 1st 10 lines with `sed -i 1,10d A.txt`

What command do I write to print those 10 deleted lines to file B?

I tried `sed -i 1,10d A.txt >> B.txt` which didn't work.

Comment: sed -n 1,10p A.txt > B.txt

Comment: Hi Kamaraj,I have a doubt whether the above command will just print the first 10 lines to File B or it will first delete the 10 lines from file A and print those 10 deleted lines to file B.In my case,I have to delete frist 10 lines from file A as well as print those deleted 10 lines from file A to file B.

Comment: Please use paragraphs and do not write "I´m new to Unix". It is just noise and sounds desperate.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sed` and the `sed` script

```
1,10{
    w otherfile
    d
}
```

This will write lines 1 to 10 into the file `otherfile` while deleting them from the input.

With in-place editing of the original file (using GNU `sed` here):

```
sed -i '1,10{w B.txt
        d}' A.txt
```

The newline is needed to delimit the filename.  Or,

```
sed -i -e '1,10{w B.txt' -e 'd}' A.txt
```

Comment: sed -i -e '1,10{w B.txt' -e 'd}' A.txt

Answer (score 1):

With `ksh93`:

```
{ head >> B.txt; cat 1<>; A.txt; } < A.txt
```

If your `cat` is GNU `cat`, it will complain that it's stdout refers to the same file as its stdin. You can work around that by using `cat|cat` instead of `cat`, or use `ksh93`'s `cat` builtin for instance by using `command /opt/ast/bin/cat` instead of `cat`, or putting `/opt/ast/bin` ahead of `$PATH`.

The `1<>;` redirection operator behaves like the standard `1<>` operator (open in read+write mode *without truncation*) except that it also truncates the file *in the end* if the redirected command was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your requirements is:

- Write first 10 lines of file A into file B
- Remove first 10 lines of file A with `sed -i 1,10d A.txt`

You can do it in the following way:

```
head -10 A.txt > B.txt
sed -i 1,10d A.txt
```

The first command will write the first 10 lines of file A.txt into B.txt 
The second command (as suggested by you) will delete the first 10 lines from file A.txt

Note that in order to get the first 10 lines, you should do it **before those lines were deleted**

Comment: Hi Yaron, I need to first delete those 10 lines from file A and then print those 10 deleted lines from file A to file B and not vice versa which you suggested,like redirect those 10 deleted lines to file B.

Comment: Why do you need to delete those 10 lines before writing them into another file?

Comment: It's was an interview question mate so I was confused and thought would ask it here.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand the interview question correctly. I'm not aware of a way to restore deleted lines from a file....

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this using sed with pipes

```
sed -n '1,10p' a.txt > b.txt | sed -i '1,10d' a.txt
```

the first 10 lines from `a.txt` will be copied to `b.txt` then the first 10 lines `a.txt` will be deleted.

Comment: instead of pipe, you should use &&
sed -n '1,10p' a.txt > b.txt && sed -i '1,10d' a.txt

Comment: yh , does the same thing

Comment: Indeed; what's left for the pipe to read when you've redirected the output to b.txt?